# Taxonomy customization In Schema

Tags: web8.5, schema, taxonomy

Can we have an ability to select Keyword rather than Category while creating Schema field(Text) with option value selected from Category and while creating Component based on this Schema user can see only selected Keyword(schema level) and respective child Keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Venu says, unfortunately, there isn't currently any out-of-the-box way to select only a certain Keyword (and the hierarchy below) in the Schema.

Some options you may want to consider include:

1. Specifying the default value to be the Keyword that you want to start from (as Venu says) and giving editors clear guidelines (possibly in the field description)
2. Writing a GUI extension, Alchemy extension or Custom URL to give this behaviour
3. Determining whether your taxonomy structure is actually correct, or whether the different branches of Keywords should actually be their own Categories
4. Handle this using the Event System when the author tries to save the items and give them a error message
5. Consider whether you can use the BluePrinting and demote some Keywords/branches so that they're unavailable for editors to select within the content layer. I did this recently where we had two brands within the same company sharing some of the same Categories.

If none of these are suitable and you're not in a hurry for this functionality, then you should consider raising this requirement on the SDL Tridion Ideas page of the Community site: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/

Comment: Thanks Jonathan and Venu for quick reply , will take these as input to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

on the CM side there is no option available to choose only the keyword while creating the schema.

Can you give more details on what you are trying to achieve by choosing only the keyword? 
You can choose the category, and default to certain keyword if required.